# Selenium python if conditions logic issue

Tags: python, selenium, for-loop, if-statement, web-scraping

I have the following for loop with try/expect and if statements. Basically, I have a list of links that i am looping over, and then loading the 'targetPage' and want to extract the text value of the XPath, however there could be multiple paths, so i set them up in variables. There is a problem with the logic, the output keeps going to the expect.

My goal is to print the XPath text value if one of XPath variables is present on the page, if not then print the expect message.

```
for index, urls in enumerate(links):
  driver.get(urls)
  time.sleep(5)

  try:

    driver.get("https://targetPage.com") 

    time.sleep(5)

    mValue = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[18]/div[2]/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td[2]')
    mValue2 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[17]/div[2]/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td[2]')

    pName = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/aside/div[2]/div/a')

    if mValue:
      print(mValue.text + ' from: ' + pName.text)
      time.sleep(5)

    else: 
        continue
    
    if mValue2:
        print(mValue2.text + ' from: ' + pName.text)
        time.sleep(5)
    else: continue

  
  except NoSuchElementException:
    print('No value found from:  ' + urls)
```

Comment: Please fix the indentation in your post.  We can't tell which lines are supposed to be part of the loop.

Comment: Post the correct URL and the full code you've tried, with the above code we can't debug anything.